# How can I detonate my chicken?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The Witch Doctor "Hex" skill as a rune "Angry Chicken" where I can temporarily transform my corporeal form into that of a deadly exploding chicken.  Fun, right?

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make my chicken explode.  He just sort of stands there, or flaps about.  Clicking on things doesn't seem to make anything interesting happen - not even a tentative peck.  I thought maybe I exploded when the time ran out, but I just sort of poofed back into my normal form instead.  The tooltips for the skill and rune are no help.

How can I unleash my mighty chicken wrath upon my enemies?

Comment: I applaud this noble pursuit.

Comment: dammit, I should've made an "eggsplode" joke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your hotbar changes while self-hexed just like the Wizard's Archon transformation, though the skills aren't nearly as powerful (but they're still just as awesome).

Hit any of your skills (<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>) when in poultry form to explode.

[image]

Comment: Well, that was underwhelming.  More of a gag than a skill worth using.

Comment: @agent86 it's like a really shitty version of the Wizard's [Explosive Blast](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/explosive-blast), though you get slightly more control over it, you completely lose the ability to cast other spells in the meanwhile